# Error while executing command with Cron

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I'm trying for a while to execute a php script in my website using Cron with Cpanel.

But I get always error sent by email :

When using : `php http://mysubdomaine.mysite.com/job/job.php` ;

I get this error :

```
404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.14
Content-type: text/html
No input file specified
```

Using : `/usr/local/bin/php -f http://mysubdomaine.mysite.com/job/job.php` ;

I get this:

```
Could not open input file: http://mysubdomaine.mysite.com/job/job.php
```

But the php file http://mysubdomaine.mysite.com/job/job.php exists in my website, and when I type the path in the browser, the script execute.

I've also tried with wget but always errors.

What the problem here ?

Thanks.

Comment: You were on the right track with wget, unlike the php command, it expects a URL.  What errors did wget give you?

Comment: using `wget http://mysubdomaine.mysite.ch/job/job.php` ; I get this `/bin/sh: /usr/bin/wget: Permission denied`

Comment: which user's cron are you running this under?  wget tries to save the requested url to a file by default, so maybe thats what the permission errors are about, try running it with the -O /dev/null switch to send the output to the trash.

Comment: someone told me that is a problem of htaccess ; what do you think ?

Comment: nope... the problem is what i said it is in my answer below, and for the other problem (wget) its what i said above.  What happens when you run the wget command with -O /dev/null ? Or what happens when you login as the user who's cron this is running under, and do the wget command, do you get permission denied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant pass a URL to PHP from the command line, it wants a file path.  Which will be something like `/var/www/yoursite.com/html/index.php`

You can figure out the real path by looking at the $_SERVER variable. At the top of your script put

```
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
```

Hit it from the browser, and what that line prints is the info you need to pass in the command line.  That will show the full path and filename of the script.

Comment: how do you know its not running?  Its probably running, and just isn't successfully completing the desired action.  Check the error logs for your http server.

Comment: because the script open a file and add a line "Hello world" and close the file. But not seeing the Hello World line after the execution.

Comment: When I added this line : `echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];` the Cron has sended an email with the script filename in my server ! Weird ?

Comment: that would indicate the script is in fact running, its just not doing what you want.  Likely because the file its trying to open and write is using a relative path, and you're not running it from that path like you were when you called it from the browser.  hard code the full path, or change the path before executing the php command.

Comment: I changed the path to file but still getting : `/bin/sh: /usr/bin/wget: Permission denied`

Comment: @VisaMasterCard i thought you were using php -f with the full path, why did you switch it, you almost had it working? Go back to calling it with php, and use the full path in the code that opens and writes the file. that will work.  If you are switching to using wget again.. see my comment above, on your question.

Comment: Thats not a full path, thats a URL.  Do you not get the difference between a file system path and URL?  Remember when you couldn't get php to work, because you were using a URL not a path, and you changed it to a path, and it worked.  Same thing here.  Use /home/marketch/public_html/valjob/job/passes.txt as the path in the file opening and writing code.

Comment: As i said above: Use /home/marketch/public_html/valjob/job/passes.txt And I'd appreciate it if you accept my answer too.  Guess you hadn't refreshed, since the comment this is a response to is gone now.

Comment: all this problems just to open a file, am I going to have the same error when I will try to connect to the database ?

Comment: good, glad you got it working.  No, the database should be fine and not dependent on paths.  If you do have problems though, and get stuck, ask about it on a different question, this thread has gotten pretty long.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the PHP script using its local file path

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /path/to/your/script
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do `php -f myscriptbehindapache` ?

Maybe you really want to do `wget myscriptbehindapache` ?